# Can not mail log with logrotate

Tags: email, logrotate

Using logrotate to rotate logs daily. Want to email the log. The rotate is working as expected, but logs are not being emailed. I am able to generate emails from PHP using mail(), but I am not sure if I need to set up something else as a service for logrotate. I am also not sure where the logrotate mail error would be reported.

Thanks.

Details:
On Ubuntu 14.04.4 (Digital Ocean LAMP), using logrotate with /etc/logrotate.d/apache2 (config):

```
 /var/www/html/logs/my.log {
  daily
  missingok
  rotate 360
  compress
  delaycompress
  notifempty
  create
  sharedscripts
  mail me@mydomain.com
  mailfirst
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

**Make sure you can send mail**

Can your system send email? You'll likely want Postfix installed and configured. Probably to relay to another host identified by `relayhost` in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`.

You can test with `echo test | mail -s test user@example.com`.

**`/usr/bin/mail`** is the command logrotate uses by default, so if things work in your test, logrotate *should* work too.

**`logrotate`** man page excerpt:

```
   -m, --mail <command>
          Tells logrotate which command to use when mailing logs. This command should accept two arguments: 1) the subject of the message, and 2) the recipient. The command must then read a message on standard input and mail it
          to the recipient. The default mail command is /usr/bin/mail -s.
```

---

**About /usr/bin/mail**

**`/usr/bin/mail`** is a symlink (example from Ubuntu 16.04):

```
# ls -l /etc/alternatives/mail
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 May 26 09:37 /etc/alternatives/mail -> /usr/bin/bsd-mailx
# dpkg -S /usr/bin/bsd-mailx
bsd-mailx: /usr/bin/bsd-mailx
# ls -l /usr/bin/mail
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 May 26 09:37 /usr/bin/mail -> /etc/alternatives/mail
# ls -l /etc/alternatives/mail
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 May 26 09:37 /etc/alternatives/mail -> /usr/bin/bsd-mailx
# dpkg -S /usr/bin/bsd-mailx
bsd-mailx: /usr/bin/bsd-mailx
```

On this system, you could install the `mail` command with

```
# apt-get install bsd-mailx
```

**I checked and this package does exist in Ubuntu 14.04** so I think you're good. I think you can also use the `mailutils` package as an alternative.

Check your mail log (`/var/log/mail.log`). You should see exactly what is happening with the messages if they are making it to Postfix.

---

**You can debug `logrotate` if the above isn't the problem**

You can run logrotate manually and even apply `-v` for verbose mode and `-f` for force. You should see what's going on.

```
# logrotate -v -f mysql-server 
reading config file mysql-server

Handling 1 logs

rotating pattern: /var/log/mysql.log /var/log/mysql/*log  forced from command line (7 rotations)
empty log files are rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /var/log/mysql.log
  log /var/log/mysql.log does not exist -- skipping
considering log /var/log/mysql/error.log
  log needs rotating
rotating log /var/log/mysql/error.log, log->rotateCount is 7
dateext suffix '-20160924'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
renaming /var/log/mysql/error.log.7.gz to /var/log/mysql/error.log.8.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 7), 
renaming /var/log/mysql/error.log.6.gz to /var/log/mysql/error.log.7.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 6), 
renaming /var/log/mysql/error.log.5.gz to /var/log/mysql/error.log.6.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 5), 
renaming /var/log/mysql/error.log.4.gz to /var/log/mysql/error.log.5.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 4), 
renaming /var/log/mysql/error.log.3.gz to /var/log/mysql/error.log.4.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 3), 
renaming /var/log/mysql/error.log.2.gz to /var/log/mysql/error.log.3.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 2), 
renaming /var/log/mysql/error.log.1.gz to /var/log/mysql/error.log.2.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 1), 
renaming /var/log/mysql/error.log.0.gz to /var/log/mysql/error.log.1.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 0), 
old log /var/log/mysql/error.log.0.gz does not exist
renaming /var/log/mysql/error.log to /var/log/mysql/error.log.1
creating new /var/log/mysql/error.log mode = 0640 uid = 107 gid = 4
running postrotate script
compressing log with: /bin/gzip
removing old log /var/log/mysql/error.log.8.gz
```

Comment: Thanks. This has narrowed my problem down: I am using sendmail (which is working), but logrotate is trying to use the default mail. Where can I tell logrotate to use sendmail?

/etc/cron.daily/logrotate:

#!/bin/sh
# Clean non existent log file entries from status file
cd /var/lib/logrotate
test -e status || touch status
head -1 status > status.clean
sed 's/"//g' status | while read logfile date
do
 [ -e "$logfile" ] && echo "\"$logfile\" $date"
done >> status.clean
mv status.clean status

test -x /usr/sbin/logrotate || exit 0
/usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf

Comment: @user2876623 The `mail` command sends mail to sendmail. Did you try it? What do you mean by default mail?

Comment: Ryan- I did not understand that. When I try to manually run logrotate using logrotate --force /etc/logrotate.d/apache2, I get error: mail command failed for... (but log is rotated). But 'echo testmessage | sendmail -s test steve@x.com' works. And 'echo testmessage | mail -s test steve@x.com' fails saying that the program 'mail' is not installed. So I thought that 'mail' in logrotate was doing the same thing, and I needed logrotate to use sendmail in place of mail. Any ideas on my error? And thanks.

Comment: @user2876623 /usr/bin/mail is a symlink. You can install different packages for it as it uses the `alternatives` system. I believe bsd-mailx is the right package for your OS. I'll update my answer with more info about this...

Comment: @user2876623 As I quote in my answer, the man page says you can pass *`-m`* to logrotate to have it use a different mail command if you must but I suggest just installing the appropriate missing package.

Comment: @user2876623 I don't know how `echo testmessage | sendmail -s test steve@x.com`is working for you as it is not correct syntax from what I can tell and remember from 15 years ago when people still used it. https://linux.die.net/man/8/sendmail.sendmail

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that syntax was bad, but I think it just ignored the bad bits. I ended up using a workaround with a prerotate script that simply calls sendmail and passes in the log file contents: 'prerotate sendmail to@x.com < log.file endscript' -- Thanks.